# Taking the floor of a float

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floor

I have found two ways of taking floors in Python:

```
3.1415 // 1
```

and

```
import math
math.floor(3.1415)
```

The problem with the first approach is that it return a float (namely `3.0`). The second approach feels clumsy and too long.

Are there alternative solutions for taking floors in Python?

Comment: pick the second one. nothing wrong with it.

Comment: You could always call `int(3.1415)`, but rather than a floor, it rounds towards 0, which will yield a different result for numbers <0.

Comment: http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Pi_equals_exactly_three

Comment: or you could do `int(3.1415 // 1)` which works like math.floor

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As long as your numbers are positive, you can simply convert to an `int` to round down to the next integer:

```
>>> int(3.1415)
3
```

For negative integers, this will round up, though.

Comment: To get any number (positive as well as negative) to round down, there's still `int(n // 1)`, like `int(-3.14 // 1)` that gives `-4`. Of course this is only useful if negative numbers might show up.

Comment: @zezollo Unless you want to confuse readers of your code, using `int(math.floor(x))` is preferable over floor division by 1, since it's immediately obvious what it does.

Answer (score 14):

You can call int() on the float to cast to the lower int (not obviously the floor but more elegant)

```
int(3.745)  #3
```

Alternatively call int on the floor result.

```
from math import floor

f1 = 3.1415
f2 = 3.7415

print floor(f1)       # 3.0
print int(floor(f1))  # 3
print int(f1)         # 3
print int(f2)         # 3 (some people may expect 4 here)
print int(floor(f2))  # 3
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int

Comment: Why would people expect `4` for `int(f2)`?

Comment: Because you may expect it to round to the nearest int not the lower int.

Comment: The OP is using Python 3.x, which isn't quite obvious from the post.  In Python 3.x, `math.floor()` returns an `int`, so it's not necessary to convert the return value.

Answer (score 6):

The second approach is the way to go, but there's a way to shorten it.

```
from math import floor
floor(3.1415)
```

Comment: `floor()` returns an integer in python3, but in python2 it returns float.

Comment: @eugeney, I was just pointing out that there was a way to leave off the `math.` part. I wonder why they didn't complain about getting a `float` result back from `floor` in the first place? And thanks for informing me of that change from 2 to 3, I didn't know that one. It makes sense, `floor` couldn't return an `int` until arbitrary size integers were interchangeable with normal ints starting in 2.4.

Answer (score 5):

Beware that taking the floor and casting to an int are not the same thing with negative numbers. If you really want the floor as an integer, you should cast to an int after calling math.floor().

```
>>> int(-0.5)
0
>>> math.floor(-0.5)
-1.0
>>> int(math.floor(-0.5))
-1
```

Answer (score 4):

Cast it to `int` if you don't want a `float`

```
int(3.1415 // 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import floor


def ff(num, step=0):
    if not step:
        return floor(num)
    if step < 0:
        mplr = 10 ** (step * -1)
        return floor(num / mplr) * mplr
    ncnt = step
    if 1 > step > 0:
        ndec, ncnt = .0101, 1
        while ndec > step:
            ndec *= .1
            ncnt += 1
    mplr = 10 ** ncnt
    return round(floor(num * mplr) / mplr, ncnt)
```

You can use positive/negative numbers and float points .1, .01, .001...

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 1.23456
leftnumber = int(str(number).split('.')[0])
rightnumber = str(number ).split('.')[1]
```