# Python: get first number of every float in a list

Tags: python, list

python beginner here. How can I convert

```
list = [2.4, 4.8532, 5.43253, 55.3838]
```

to

```
list = [2, 4, 5, 5]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking the floor of a float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404967/taking-the-floor-of-a-float)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safest way to convert float to integer in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387655/safest-way-to-convert-float-to-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use `int()`, Since `int()` always rounds <s>down</s> toward 0, which is the equivalent of chopping the decimals for floats. Note: do not use `list` as a variable name since it's already a built-in function and type.

```
lst = [2.4, 4.8532, 5.43253]
lst = [int(x) for x in lst]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `int()` **does not** round, if you want rounding, use `round()` instead

Comment: `int()` doesn't round down; it rounds towards 0 ("chopping the decimals," as you say).

Comment: This assumes values < 10.

Comment: Thanks. What if the values are greater than 10?

Comment: @Umuko so do you mean you want to "take the first digit" instead of "take the first number"? What is your desired result for `24.8532`? `2` or `24` or `25`?

Comment: @abccd in this case I am looking for a 2. My examples were bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: And one more question, will your number have negative numbers as well?

Comment: @abccd no there won't be any negatives numbers

Comment: if it does have negative numbers: `lst = [int(str(x)[0]) if str(x)[0] != '-' else int(str(x)[1])  for x in lst]` if it doesn't, it will be easy: `lst = [int(str(x)[0]) for x in lst]`. The first way works for a list that could include both negative and non-negative numbers

Comment: `int(str(x)[0]) if str(x)[0] != '-' else int(str(x)[1])` can be more concisely expressed as `int(str(x)[x<0])`. Or you could just do `int(str(abs(x))[0])`.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @ThéophilePace it solved the OP’s problem, if you have a similar question and this solution does not work for you, you should ask a new question or search for a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new list, such as with a comprehension. You might want to get the first digit of each element, or possibly get the floor value of each element:

```
>>> l = [2.4, 4.8532, 5.43253]
>>> l2 = [12.4, 374.8532, -505.43253]
>>> list(map(int, (i[0] for i in map(str, l))))
[2, 4, 5]
>>> list(map(int, l))
[2, 4, 5]
>>> list(map(int, (i[0] for i in map(str, l2))))
>>> [i[0] for i in map(str, l2)]
['1', '3', '-']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
>>> list(map(int, l2))
[12, 374, -505]
```

Note how you will need to be more specific regarding the assumptions about the contents of the list. Can the numbers be greater than 10? Can they be negative? Do you want the first digit of a negative number, or the first character? If it's always `0 < number < 10`, you have nothing to worry about.